# If we have an irreducible and recurrent Markov Chain, how to show $\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{lim inf}X_{n}=0,\operatorname{lim sup} X_{n}=\infty)=1$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains

Let $\{X_n,n\geq0\}$ be a Markov Chain on ${0,1,2,...}$. If the Markov chain is irreducible and recurrent, then $$\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{lim inf} X_{n}=0, \operatorname{lim sup}X_{n}=\infty)=1$$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

I am trying to solve this question. I know that $$\mathbb{P}(X_n=i\operatorname{ i.o.})=1$$ if the Marcov chain is recurrent and irreducible.

So, if I let $i=0$, then $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0\operatorname{ i.o.})=1$, and this means we will infinitely many times pass $0$. This means that $$\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{lim inf} X_{n}=0)=1$$
because the smallest value of $X_n$ is $0$. And since Markov chain is irreducible, this means that we can start from $0$ to any state $M$. So, the biggest number for $X_n$ is $M$, which state $M$ can be any number. Thus, $$\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{lim sup} X_{n}=\infty)=1$$

I am not sure if it is right idea, or I am on the right track.

If I am right, but I still do not know how to write this idea mathematically.

Comment: What you claim to "know" is wrong, and in fact it directly contradicts what you are asked to prove: the events $\lim\sup X_n=\infty$ and $\lim\sup X_n=i$ are mutually exclusive, so, they cannot both hold with probability 1. You might start e.g. by reading the definition of $\lim\inf$, and then trying to understand what $\lim \inf a_n=0$ means for sequence $a_n$ with values in $0,1,\dots$

Comment: $P(limsup X_n =i)=1$ is wrong, it should be replaced as $P(X_n = i, i.o.) = 1$, where $i.o.$ stands for infinitely often.

Answer (score 1):

Define two series of stopping times, $T_0,T_1,T_2,\dots$ and $S_1,S_2,\dots$, as follows:

- $T_0=0$.
- For each $i\ge 1$, $S_i=\inf \{n\mid n > T_{i-1} \text{ and }X_n=2^i\}$.
- For each $i\ge 1$, $T_i=\inf \{n\mid n > S_{i} \text{ and }X_n=0\}$.

Since the Markov process is irreducible and positive recurrent, you can show that each of these stopping times is almost surely finite (prove this). Therefore, this shows that with probability one, there both exists a subsequence $(T_0,T_1,T_2,\dots)$ along which $X_n\to 0$, and a subsequence $(S_1,S_2,\dots)$ along which $X_n\to+\infty$.